# wiredep is returing physical path, instead of relative path

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, wiredep, gruntfile

I'm trying to get the itens from wiredep in my  gruntfile, but it is always returning a physical path, like: "D:\folder\folder\file.css", while in the documentation it says that it will return a relative path (https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep#programmatic-access).

My code is:

in gruntfile:

```
var myCss = require('wiredep')().css
```

in my index.html i have:

```
<!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/normalize.css/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-snap/angular-snap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/ionicons/css/ionicons.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-carousel/dist/angular-carousel.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" />
    <!-- endbower -->
```

I want it to return an array with the path as is, ex: "bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the option `ignorePath` of `wirerep` configuration parameter. To give you more detail you should provide the full paths structure of your project folder but try something like this

```
var myCss = require('wiredep')({ignorePath: '/../../'}).css
```